# Exporting dependant variable failed in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have three shell script files, one global variable named **"VER"** and its value is "2017.4" 
 1. variable.sh 
 2. function.sh 
 3. main.sh

**variable.sh** 
`var1=/home
var2=/home/${VER}_version`

**function.sh** 
Contain a function named export_function which takes one variable as argument, perform grep operation to find that variable from ***variable.sh*** file and export the grep output

```
export_function () {
    var=`grep "$1=" variable.sh | sed -e "s/"$1="//g"`
    export $1=$var
}
```

**main.sh**

```
source function.sh
export_function var2
echo "$var2"
```

When I run the main.sh, get output: `/home/${VER}_version` instead of `/home/2017.4_version` 

Note: echo $VER in main.sh and function.sh shows value 2017.4 
**Constrains:**

1. variable.sh is a read-only file
2. `source variable.sh` is not allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've rewritten your scripts like that, and it works:

```
[sahaquiel@sahaquiel-PC ~]$ cat variable.sh 
#!/bin/bash

var1=/home
var2="/home/${VAR22}_version"
[sahaquiel@sahaquiel-PC ~]$ cat function.sh 
#!/bin/bash

export_function () {
source variable.sh
var=$(echo "var2=${var2}" | grep "$1=" | sed -e "s/"$1="//g")
export $1=$var
}
[sahaquiel@sahaquiel-PC ~]$ cat main.sh 
#!/bin/bash

source function.sh
export_function var2
echo "$var2"
[sahaquiel@sahaquiel-PC ~]$ bash main.sh
/home/2017.4_version
[sahaquiel@sahaquiel-PC ~]$ echo $VAR22
2017.4
```

Comment: It perfectly works. Sorry to mention late, variable.sh is the read-only file with more than 50 variables and modification in it is not allowed.

Comment: sorry to tell, source a variable file is also not allowed as it executes all 50 variables which is not desirable.